# ¿Como quitar el "error" "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" de este programa y que significa? (C++)

Tags: c++

El programa debe imprimir letras en orden aleatorio, y funciona bien pero el final aparece el aviso: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" y me gustaría saber por que pasa esto. investigué y parece que tiene que ver con el acceso a partes erróneas de la memoria o algo parecido pero no he encontrado la manera de removerlo.

Aquí está el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

string M[15][15];

int GetNum();
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    string Letras[27]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
        {
            int N=GetNum();

            M[i][j]=Letras[N];
            cout<<setw(5)<<M[i][j];

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

}
int GetNum()
{
    int X=0;
    X= rand()%26;
    return X;
}
```

De antemano gracias por su tiempo, ¡saludos!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El subíndice `j` se pasa del límite (estás usando 16).  El subíndice máximo que debe alcanzar dentro del *array* es 14 (va de 0 a 14 para un total de 15 elementos).

Un par de recomendaciones:

1. Puedes declarar y definir la función `getInt()` antes de la función `main()`.
2. Cuando utilices constantes para los límites es aconsejable no usar números *mágicos*.  Por ejemplo, puedes usar una constante para los límites de la primera y segunda dimensión

```
constexpr int FILAS = 15;
constexpr int COLUMNAS = 15;

string M[FILAS][COLUMNAS];
```

Al iterar puedes usar esos límites (y evitar un "error de dedo").

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que estas tratando de acceder a un espacio de memoria en el vector M que no existe, ya que si el tamaño es 15 los indices de la matriz van de 0 a 14 y cuando colocas j < 16 se intenta acceder al elemento en la posición 15, la cual no existe.

Debes cambiar el indice mayor del segundo ciclo FOR:

```
for(int i=0;i<14;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<15;j++)
        {
            int N=GetNum();

            M[i][j]=Letras[N];
            cout<<setw(5)<<M[i][j];

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

colocando 14 y 15 porque asumo que quieres que funcione con esa lógica.